# How to use pgrypto in postgres to hash password

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, hash, pdo

I usually hash password+salt with sha1 and inserted password hash and salt into MySQL database. Now I have to use postgres in new project (PHP project) and I get known, there are better  ways to salt password. I found this [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html) and code:

```
  UPDATE ... SET pswhash = crypt('new password', gen_salt('md5'));
SELECT pswhash = crypt('entered password', pswhash) FROM ... ;
```

But I don't understand this way at all. Could You explain me what I need to have in database and how to get these values? I use PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres' `crypt()` is similar to PHP's `crypt()` and (if I read the docs correctly) identical to PHP5.5's password extension when using a blowfish salt (which is the one you should use):

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

The underlying idea behind the algorithm is to give a unique salt for each password, and to store this unique salt as part of the hashed password. This allows to hash a password using the hashed password, as the following should illustrate:

```
denis=# select gen_salt('bf');
           gen_salt            
-------------------------------
 $2a$06$DOCbBUPOHRoXVQ9S0IKle.
(1 row)

denis=# select crypt('test', '$2a$06$DOCbBUPOHRoXVQ9S0IKle.');
                            crypt                             
--------------------------------------------------------------
 $2a$06$DOCbBUPOHRoXVQ9S0IKle.atXit.S89NpRb6J6S9S7xfNeZx7Md4e
(1 row)

denis=# select crypt('test', '$2a$06$DOCbBUPOHRoXVQ9S0IKle.atXit.S89NpRb6J6S9S7xfNeZx7Md4e');
                            crypt                             
--------------------------------------------------------------
 $2a$06$DOCbBUPOHRoXVQ9S0IKle.atXit.S89NpRb6J6S9S7xfNeZx7Md4e
(1 row)
```

As an aside, you'll probably want to hash the data directly using PHP 5.5's `password_hash()`, so as to avoid carting unhashed passwords around unnecessarily between PHP and the database. Assuming you do, use Postgres' `crypt()` as a conveniently compatible utility if you ever need to import rows with unhashed passwords without resorting to php.

Comment: I get known some about password_hash() in PHP 5.5 and I decided to use it, I think it's great way to have safety login system. However, I don't what is maximum length of hash form password_hash(). How big should be column in my database?

Comment: That would depend on the hash. For bcrypt, it's 60 bytes, i.e. char(60).

Comment: im missing something here. Do i need two fields? One for store the salt and one for the hashed field?

Comment: @Gonzalo: The salt is part of the stored hash. Notice how `'$2a$06$DOCbBUPOHRoXVQ9S0IKle.'` gets passed around in the example.